# macOS folder in Storage Management will not 'Show in Finder', searching Finder for folder name finds nothing. How do I locate a folder?

Tags: macos, storage

There is a folder in 'iOS files' with a nonfriendly name, like 056161156-651E66560561 and if I select it and choose the **Show in Finder** button, nothing happens.

The same button works for other folders.

If I manually enter the name in the search box of a normal finder window, it cannot find it.

How to locate this folder so I can decide whether to delete it or not? It's taking up over 50 GB!

Comment: It's probably backups of your iPhone/iPad.

Answer (score 1):

[EasyFind](https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/freeware) (freeware) will find anything, even things Spotlight/Finder will not.

Set to search files & folders and include invisible.
It's much slower than the Mac's native find because it isn't indexed, it scours the drive looking for matches - but it will find them.

[image]